# how to make nested table pdf using jspdf

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, jspdf-autotable, nested-table

I have a nested table in a that only shows up when there is more than one data point in the object used to build the table. This nested table only shows up in a few rows with in the table. The rest of the table generates as normal how can i achieve this functionality,
here is my json file

```
[
   {
       "day": "Saturday",
       "date": "7 August 2021",
       "siteline":[
         {  
            "timein": "04:00PM",
            "timeout": "12:00AM",
            "hours": "8:00"
         }
      ]
   },
    {
       "day": "Saturday",
       "date": "7 August 2021",
       "siteline":[
         {  
            "timein": "04:00PM",
            "timeout": "12:00AM",
            "hours": "8:00"
         },
          {  
            "timein": "04:00PM",
            "timeout": "12:00AM",
            "hours": "8:00"
         }
      ]
   },
    {
       "day": "Saturday",
       "date": "7 August 2021",
       "siteline":[
         {  
            "timein": "04:00PM",
            "timeout": "12:00AM",
            "hours": "8:00"
         },
          {  
            "timein": "04:00PM",
            "timeout": "12:00AM",
            "hours": "8:00"
         }
      ]
   },
    {
       "day": "Saturday",
       "date": "7 August 2021",
       "siteline":[
         {  
            "timein": "04:00PM",
            "timeout": "12:00AM",
            "hours": "8:00"
         },
          {  
            "timein": "04:00PM",
            "timeout": "12:00AM",
            "hours": "8:00"
         }
      ]
   },
    {
       "day": "Saturday",
       "date": "7 August 2021",
       "siteline":[
         {  
            "timein": "04:00PM",
            "timeout": "12:00AM",
            "hours": "8:00"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

and this is code which is not work as expected

```
import jsPDF from "jspdf";
import "jspdf-autotable";
import data from "../../Data/PdfMainData.json";
const GeneratePdf = () => {
  const doc = new jsPDF();
  const tableRows = [];
  const userNestedData = [];
  data.map((item) => {
  
    const userData = [
      item.day,
      item.date,
      item.siteline.length > 0
        ? item.siteline.map(
          (value) => (

            value.timein,
            value.timeout,
            value.hours,
            value.sitename
          )
        )
        : null,
    ];
   
    tableRows.push(userData);
   
  });
 
  doc.autoTable({
    head: [
      [
        "Day",
        "Date",
        "Time In",
        "Time Out",
        "Hours",
        "Site/Corporation Name",

      ],
    ],
    body: tableRows,
    theme: "grid",
    // margin: { top: 50 },
  });

  const date = Date().split(" ");
  const dateStr = date[0] + date[1] + date[2] + date[3] + date[4];
  // doc.text("User List", 14, 15);
  doc.save(`report_${dateStr}.pdf`);
};

export default GeneratePdf;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this, you can achieve.

```js
for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){    
  autoTable(doc,{
    body:data[i].siteline,
    columns:[
      {header:'timein', dataKey:'timein'},
      {header:'timeout', dataKey:'timeout'},
      {header:'hours', dataKey:'hours'},
    ],
    theme: 'grid',
    styles: {
      overflow: 'linebreak',
      fontSize: 6,
    },
    showHead: 'everyPage',
  })
}  
doc.save('data.pdf');
```